# Batch Taskkill by runtime

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2012

Is there a way to execute a batch to kill a process based on runtime?
Background info: Server 2012 task scheduler has problems running correctly. I found a freemium alternative but it doesn't detech if a process has been stuck.  I have a schedule that tries to run every 5 min but takes up to 30 min to run normally. Every few days, it may hang. I set up a script to Find process before running again. However I do not know how to get it to end the program if it is stuck.

I cannot use TIMEOUT because the program runs gap time is every 5 minutes. But the program can take longer than that to finish.

```
Detect if process has run passed a certain time.
TASKKILL notepad.exe
goto END
:END
START notepad.exe
```

Comment: "Server 2012 task scheduler has problems running correctly."  It is more likely a simple [PEBCAK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK).  This is more of a [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) kind of question btw.

Comment: Thanks I'll post on SuperUser to see if anyone knows.  I didn't give a history of the Task Scheduler issue since it wasn't the focus of my question.  Just for other people's reference, The Task Scheduler would run fine for a few days then just stop working.  Even worse, the history shows that the schedule was working but since I had the event trigger a bat log file before running the program, the log showed it didn't actually trigger.  Using task scheduler to manually run the schedule worked but the schedule itself never worked properly again.  This occurred for multiple servers.